# localstorage and iframe issue

Tags: iframe, local-storage

I am creating a preview for users entering html but I am having problems sharing the html across an iframe.

I have the following javascript

```
$(function () {
    var pathname =  "https://" + document.domain + "/newspreview.aspx";
    localStorage.contents = $("#<%=Content.ClientID%>").val();
    $("#preview").attr("src", pathname);
});
```

and the html is

```
<iframe id="preview" style="border:2px solid; width:880px;height:600px;" >

  </iframe>
```

on the newspreview.aspx page I have the javascript below, all I get displayed is undefined. 
Has anybody got any ideas why this is the case. (BTW both pages are using https)

```
 <script type="text/javascript" language="javascript">
         var result = localStorage.contents;
         document.write(result);
         localStorage.removeItem("contents");
</script>
```

Regards

Podge

Comment: Are they on the same domain?

Comment: Is this in all [browsers](http://www.quirksmode.org/dom/html5.html), or just one... if it it's just one, I don't suppose it's IE?

Comment: they have the following urls http://www.localdev.*******.local/Admin/editor.aspx and http://www.localdev.*******.local/newspreview.aspx. The browsers that i am using are firefox and chrome.